# Is there a way I can enable a display without attaching it to desktop through Windows API?

Tags: c++, windows, multiple-monitors

I only need a display for DXGI output, and don't want it to be a part of desktop at all. I really don't want the fullscreened display to exit fullscreen mode just because someone has accidentally moved some window out of the main desktop or so.

Is there a way to enable a display without making it a part of desktop?

---

"Note  Using other monitors as independent displays isn't supported on drivers that are implemented to the Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM)."

Guess I have no luck.

Comment: Just a wild guess but maybe [Windows SideShow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_SideShow) will offer what you need.

Comment: I'm not very sure, but it seems SideShow uses a seperate driver. I need the display do direct3d real-time rendering.